# django authenticationform not showing all errors

Tags: django, forms, authentication

My login works fine except for not showing all errors. When i type  an invalid username or password, these errors don't show and the page just refreshes without putting any errors down.

However when i leave one field blank, it shows the correct error:

So the missing errors are(from source):

```
error_messages = {
    'invalid_login': _("Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. "
                       "Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."),
    'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
}
```

my code:

```
def login_user(request):
    """Logs a user into the application."""
    auth_form = AuthenticationForm(None, request.POST or None)

    # The form itself handles authentication and checking to make sure password and such are supplied.
    if auth_form.is_valid():
       (request, auth_form.get_user())
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'auth_form': auth_form})
```

My template:

```
<form action="{% url 'login_user' %}" method="post" class="login">{% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <input name="username" placeholder="Username:" type="text" name="username"     value="" id="username" class="login">
        {{ auth_form.username.errors }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="password" placeholder="Password:" type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" class="login">
        {{ auth_form.password.errors }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <center>
            <a href="{% url 'register_user' %}">
                register
            </a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="submit" class="link">
                login
            </button>
        </center>
    </div>
</form>
```

what do i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't including `form.non_field_errors` in your template. See the docs on [customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template) for an example.

As an aside, the `AuthenticationForm` takes the request as its first argument. It looks slightly strange that you are passing `None` instead of `request`.